# What do you call a process in which both sides are affected?

Tags: word-request

> **Food production affects climate change and climate change affects food production.**

So, climate change is a ___ process?

I am writing a summary, so I should paraphrase this sentence like

> Regarding the application of resources he concretizes that climate change is a ___ process.

Comment: *Symbiotic* and *interdependent* may work.

Comment: It's really a *feedback* process.

Comment: It's a cyclical process.

Comment: Does this need to be a single word, or are you fine with a [tag:phrase-request] as well?

Comment: Mutually dependent

Comment: Uh ... I guess, bilateral should work.

Comment: concretize is not a verb  in English, by the way. He specifies or specifically states that....//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of relationships which describe the connection in your sentence, in a

> feedback loop

there is an explicit, direct link between the processes, one part is dependent on the other. An example is a heating system and a thermostat:

> 1) thermostat reading is cold
>   2) thermostat turns on heater
>   3) heater heats room
>   4) thermostat reading is hot
>   5) thermostat turns off heater

another example is supplying oxygen to an active body

> 1) person becomes active
>   2) activity causes oxygen deprivation
>   3) heart and breathing rate increase to compensate
>   4) person stops activity
>   5) heart and breathing rate decrease

another kind of relationship is a

> reciprocal process

an example of this is humidity and rainfall

> 1) water evaporates
>   2) humidity increases
>   3) air becomes saturated
>   4)  it rains
>   5) rain water evaporates

in a reciprocal relationship, the parts are not explicitly linked but can be related. Just because water evaporates, does not mean it will rain.

*Symbiosis* is a type of a *reciprocal relationship*, clown fish and anemones are an example

[image]
<sub>(source: [ocellarisclownfish.com](http://www.ocellarisclownfish.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Fotolia_52922103_XS.jpg))</sub>

In your example,

> food production effects climate change

it is well known that irrigation and farming practices can effect gas levels and geography which can then effect climate. The change in climate may effect what types of plants and animals are grown, though over a long period of time.

Because humans are involved in deciding what gets farmed, this may be thought of as a *feedback loop* if climate change effects the farmer's decisions. Otherwise it is merely a statement about causality (very simply)

> 1) farmers grow cows
>   2) cows emit methane, a greenhouse gas
>   3) earth temperature rises
>   4) water becomes scarce since the saturation point rises
>   5) brought causes lack of feed production
>   6) cows die

Possibly the speaker in your example might use

> cause and effect process

since the closing of the "loop" is not explicitly stated.